# Angular 5: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable

Tags: javascript, angular, html, angular5, ngfor

I encountered an error in Angular 5 when adding a for loop in the table. I tried to find the reason but they are not clear enough and I cannot solve the problem. My code and the error as follows.

```
<tr *ngFor="let template of templates; let j=index">
    <td><b>Template {{j+1}}</b></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="template"/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: ngModel variable and ngFor reference variable cannot be same.

Comment: What type of element is "template"?. to show value you can try [innerHTML]="template"

Comment: Can you show component code and line number where this error occurs?

Comment: What you mean is they are cannot be exactly the same variable? this error will always occur when the array (templates in this case) is not an array of object? @A.Sakkeer

Comment: @sixerss the templates is an array of string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let template creates a local variable and ngModel can't assign to local variables. You can only assign to properties (fields) of your component.

but you can try in component :

```
public templates = ['test', 'test'];
public customTrackBy(index: number, obj: any): any {
    return  index;
}
```

template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let template of templates; let j=index ;  trackBy:customTrackBy">
    <td><b>Template {{j+1}}</b></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="templates[j]"/></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should Work:

```
<tr *ngFor="let template of templates; let j=index">
  <td><b>Template {{j+1}}</b></td>
  <td><input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="templates[j]"/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: by this way input field looses focus after the first letter is entered .

Comment: Ah Yes. Got the reason. Thank You

Comment: @Jimmy this answer is not correct based on above comment , please check my answer too. and accept one of them.

Comment: @fatemefazli You're right. Your answer is really cool. Thanks a lot. You make me learn a lesson.